# Scrapy returns 200 and image URL but does not save the image file

Tags: python, scrapy

How do I save the file? The folder is created but no data is saved.

I have checked several online posts for advice but cannot resolve the issue.
Why is the URL not passed to the item loader? Reading the docs

```
import scrapy
from matsuscrapy2.items import ImageItem


class Matsuscrape22Spider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'matsuscrape22'
start_urls = ['https://www.matsukiyo.co.jp/store/online/p/4902102113632'
                  ]

def parse(self, response):
    yield ImageItem(image_urls="https://www.matsukiyo.co.jp" + response.xpath('*//div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li/img/@src').extract()[0])
```

output-

> 2021-06-27 21:48:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200       [https://www.matsukiyo.co.jp/store/online/p/4902102113632>](https://www.matsukiyo.co.jp/store/online/p/4902102113632%3E)
> {'image_urls':
> 'https://www.matsukiyo.co.jp/medias/4902102113632-1.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wxNDA4MTJ8aW1hZ2UvanBlZ3xzeXMtbWFzdGVyL2ltYWdlcy9oZjUvaDM4LzkwMTI2Njk4NzQyMDYvNDkwMjEwMjExMzYzMl8xLmpwZ3w0N2FhMTNkNzU5NGIxZTNkZDk4ZDJhMjc0NWZlNGJiYmM2MTkzNWQ5ZTNjMTJiNjlkZDU0NjYxZGQ4ZDEzYmE0'}

items.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item

class ImageItem(scrapy.Item):
image_urls = scrapy.Field()
images = scrapy.Field()
```

settings.py

```
IMAGE_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = "images"
```

How am I supposed to set up the pipelines.py file
the default config is not returning the image and the documentation does not mention the pipeline.py file in much detail

Any advice would be great thank you

Answer (score 1):

Change your yield from this:

```
yield ImageItem(image_urls="https://www.matsukiyo.co.jp" + response.xpath('*//div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li/img/@src').extract()[0])
```

to this:

```
yield {'image_urls': ["https://www.matsukiyo.co.jp" + response.xpath('*//div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li/img/@src').extract()[0]]}
```

You don't have to overwrite imagepipeline if you just want to get images.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, however the result is exactly the same, the link is generated and correct(you can click the link form the terminal and the site opens the image) however the image is not saved by Scrapy.
Do you have another suggestion that could help? Thank you for your assistance

Comment: This answer helped me... I was having trouble with data override due to ImageItem yielded... Thank you very much!